# Input data and scrape using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to input latitude and longitude to http://www.earthpoint.us/TownshipsSearchByLatLon.aspx and scrape resulting township information

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.earthpoint.us/TownshipsSearchByLatLon.aspx")
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("ContentPlaceHolder1_Latitude")
elem2 = driver.find_element_by_id("ContentPlaceHolder1_Longitude")

latitude = '32.8699363',
longitude = '-93.9224662'

elem.send_keys(latitude)
elem2.send_keys(longitude)

elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

This opens the page with needed info.

Would I just use something like `needed_info = driver.find_element_by_xpath('some_path')`

Also is selenium the best way to do it? And is there a way not to open a browser window?

I have checked several threads on stackoverflow and `selenium` package seems to be the simplest to use. Would `mechanize` be better?

Comment: `mechanize` can't handle JavaScript so probably it isn't better for your case.

Comment: The question is not whether JS is needed or not, but whether you need to *interactively* control a real browser, e.g. by typing. If you could just POST your long & lat to an endpoint/URL and get a parseable data object back, then Mechanize or pure HTTP would be much better. In this case, Selenium is probably the best way.

Comment: I believe I have to "type" lat and long inside browser because the URL of the page doesn't change. I have experience scraping that way. But its my first time using selenium and inputing data into browser for scraping

Comment: No, it's AJAX. When you click the button a POST request is sent, so you could potentially parse the results from the response. It looks possible. I'm not saying you have to change, just that there are alternatives that may be quicker.

Answer (score 0):

```
elem3 =  [symbol.text for symbol in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_LatLonLiteralDiv"]//table//tr[2]//td[@style="border: solid 1px black; padding: 6px"]//table[@width="225"]//tr//td[2]') if symbol.text]
elem3 = elem3[0].split(',')
print elem3
```

That way I get the information I need.

Comment: Try HtmlUnitDriver. It is headless and works very well for the simplest pages. Failing that, try PhantomJS.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. I've removed the *another question* in your answer.

Comment: The browser part part of the question is in the original question also.